# Trouble to understand the proof of greedy algorithm for set cover

Tags: approximation, set-cover

**Problem definition:** Given a universe $U$ of $n$ elements, a collection of subsets of $U$, $S = \{S_1,..., S_k\}$, and a cost function $c: S \to Q^{+}$. Find a minimum cost subcollection of $S$ that covers all elements of $U$.

**The provided algorithm (Approximation algorithms - Vijay V. Vazirani)**

[image]

**Part of the proof where I have trouble to understand**
[image]

**My question**

I have a difficult time to understand the last in equality, if $|\bar{C}| \leq n - k + 1$, why does $\cfrac{OPT}{|\bar{C}|} \leq \cfrac{OPT}{n - k + 1}$ hold?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $|\bar{C}| \ge n-k +1$, not $|\bar{C}| \le n-k+1$.
The quantity $\frac{OPT}{|\bar{C}|}$ can only increase when we replace $\bar{C}$ with something that is at most as large. In our case we replace it with $n-k+1$.

Then:
$$
\frac{OPT}{|\bar{C}|} \le \frac{OPT}{n-k+1},
$$
as desired.

Comment: Oh snap, I misreaded the text. Thanks.